# DecisionTree cannot predict my data , using data from csv and read it in decisiontree

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to use decisiontree, get the data from the csv file, but seems the code cant predict my data, event hough they can read my csv file,
decision = dec_tree.predict(data) doesnt work..

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'decisiontree'
require 'csv'

attributes = ['Doc','PhPagi','PhSore','Kec','score']    
training = []
csv = CSV.read ('/Users/reynard/Desktop/Ruby/test.csv')
csv.each do |row|
training << row.map{|convert| convert.to_f }
end

puts training.inspect

dec_tree = DecisionTree::ID3Tree.new(attributes, training, 2, :discrete)
dec_tree.train
```

## how to predict this data set,using data from csv

```
data = [26.0, 7.8, 8.0, 35.0] 

puts data.inspect

decision = dec_tree.predict(data)

puts "predicted: #{decision}"


if decision == 0
  puts "Water Condition Very BAD"
elsif decision == 1
  puts "Water Condition BAD "
elsif decision == 2
  puts "Water Condition Not so Good"    
elsif decision == 3
  puts "Water Contion Normal"
elsif decision == 4
  puts "Water Contion Good"
elsif decision == 5 
  puts " Water Contion Very Good"
else
  puts "dont understand"
end
```

Comment: Consider using a hash-based lookup table instead of a pile of `if` statements chained together. `puts DESCRIPTION[decision]` is one line of code.

Comment: thanks tadman, but seems the problem isnt in the if statements..
the problem is the it cant read the "data = [26.0, 7.8, 8.0, 35.0]" from the csv file..

Comment: Read the file: `CSV.parse(File.read('data.csv'))`.

Comment: thanks Mr Tadman.. I did try.. bust still cant read..

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific as to what didn't work and what error you got, if any.

Comment: (1.) they can read the data from the csv file alrd..
this is the result from "puts training.inspect"
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [26.0, 7.8, 8.0, 35.0, 5.0], [27.0, 7.8, 8.1, 35.0, 5.0], [28.0, 7.8, 8.3, 35.0, 5.0]

(2.) ["26", "7.8", "8", "35"] this is the result from "data.inspect"

(3.) predicted: dont understand 
the result should be " 5 " and the water condition should be Very Good 

i am having problem that the data cannot read the data inside the csv..

Thank you Mr Tadman